static IP needed for rsync over ssh?
Hello Fellow Ubuntu Discoursers:
I use rsync over ssh to back up several ubuntu 22.04 computers to a pi 4b that is running ubuntu 22.04.
The ability to do this depends on my knowing the IP addresses of all of my computers.
It works quite well...UNTIL... the IP addresses of the computers change.
I don't know why they change, but they do.
I've found descriptions on how to set a static IP address on my computers using a nice gui interface: https://tecadmin.net/how-to-configure-static-ip-address-on-ubuntu-22-04/
My question (s) is (are): How do I specify

the Netmask number,
the Gateway number, and
the DNS number??

Also, are there other "gotchas"???
Thanks,
Old

IP addresses can be automatically assigned by your router by using the DHCP protocol. An IP address can be split into a network address and a host part. All hosts in the same network are assumed to be able to talk to eachother and there will be a route that says, reach this network over this network interface.
For internal networks you can use 10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/12 and 192.168.0.0/16 addresses. For example you can use 10.0.0.1 as IP address for your router and 10.0.0.2 for your raspberry pi and 10.0.0.3 and higher for your ubuntu's.
The netmask defines how many bytes are reserver for the network and the rest is used for the host part. /24 is the same as 255.255.255.0, which means that the first 3 bytes are used for the network. For example 10.0.0 is the network and .1 is the host part.
IP addresses that are set automatically by the route may change because DHCP only assigns the address for a limited time and it can choose to use or not use the same IP address in the renewal. If you have control over the DHCP server you can configure it to hand out static addresses. But this may not be possible in your case.
Once the ip addresses are set there are routes that apply. This will be used to send packets over the network and decide which interface to use. For instance the default route will go to your router (the gateway) that knows how to connect to the internet and 10.0.0.0/24 will tell which interface to use to find the other hosts in the network
default via 10.0.0.1 dev eth0
10.0.0.0/24 dev eth0

DNS translates names like google.com to IP addresses. Most of the time your router can do this, because it got information from your internet provider. Then you can set the resolver to 10.0.0.1 ... But you can also use public internet resolvers like 1.1.1.1 by Cloudflare or 8.8.8.8 by Google or 9.9.9.9 by Quad9.
DNS is not needed for your internal network if you use IP addresses, but you can use a DNS server for your host as well.
The gotcha's is that it's not always obvious to see where mistakes are made, if you can ping between two hosts you can check that it works. Most of the time I try to troubleshoot analytically by looking if the network lights blink, then if the link is established, then if the IP addresses can ping eachother, before I check if the service works and then you might run into firewalls blocking connections. I tend to make drawings to vizualize which connections work and where the problem is.

I'm not supposed to say "thank you." So, I won't.

Thanks again, for your scholarly reply. While I've used Ubuntu since 06, and done alot of tinkering with it, I don't have the type of understanding to fully appreciate your reply. My applogies! I was hoping for a simple "how to," preferable a gui approach. thanks, Old
